# OneDrive/SharePoint: Prevent users from full-syncing folders/files

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive

I have a client that would like to restrict their employees (users) from syncing the entire SharePoint files library.  Instead, they'd like it so users can only sync certain files or folders.  Ideally, AAD integration would be great so they can be like user X can sync Folders A, B and C but user Y can only sync B and D.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my test there is no feasible solution for your needs at this moment. For now, we just could limit files to sync at site level or library level, there is no way to limit at folder level per users.

Here is an official article for your reference: [Limit sync for a SharePoint site (microsoft.com)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/limit-sync-for-a-sharepoint-site-e17bf52b-fa5d-41cf-9eb0-d3812542424e)

Answer (score 0):

Matt,

This is less of an answer and more sharing of my limited experience. If part of what you're trying to accomplish is editing permissions this may help.

Create three AD groups:

1. GROUP Everyone = All Users
2. GROUP ALPHA = User X
3. GROUP BETA = User Y

MASTER FOLDER - This is the overall all encompassing folder and the AD Group "Everyone" has been assigned to it with having Viewing permissions. [this is the folder that everyone syncs and thus sees].  Then the following folders live within it.

Add the AD groups to SharePoint like so:

- FOLDER A - GROUP ALPHA assigned to it with Member permissions (read,
  write, edit)
- FOLDER B - GROUP ALPHA & BETA assigned to it with Member permissions (read, write, edit)
- FOLDER C - GROUP ALPHA assigned to it with Member permissions (read, write, edit)
- FOLDER D - GROUP BETA assigned to it with Member permissions (read, write, edit)

I doubt this will completely answer your question or meet your needs. I just wanted to show you how to manage permissions within SharePoint as a possible way to manage access if that is what you're looking to regulate that.  Using AD help administer permissions with less effort.

Peace,